# Get data from closed file with partly known name while also checking for more than one file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a closed Excel sheet and paste it into a worksheet in the active workbook.

I have a file with both a date and time stamp

I only care about the date stamp. There could be 2 for the same date with different time stamps.

The file would be called: 'testYYYYMMDD_HHMMSS'
Filepath = 'H:\data\test\'

The code so far is (where SFD is a YYYYMMDD format in a cell in the worksheet):

```
Sub NowOpenClosedWorkbook()

    Dim SFD As Range
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String

    Set SFD = Sheets("Sam's Test").Range("C2")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("H:\data\test\" & SamsFileDate & "_??????.xlsx")
    wbName = xWb.Name
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "This workbook does not exist", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Err.Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "The workbook is opened", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    End If
End Sub
```

The end goal:

- The file I need the data from shouldn't open
- The program should check if there more than one file with 'testYYYYMMDD_HHMMSS' only have one a day, however there could be 2. In this scenario, it alerts the user and stops the program.

Comment: just loop over files in the directory, add the names to a dictionary, and break once you get a duplicate

Comment: Get & Transform wouldn't open the files in Excel, just read the data. Might fit your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use the `Dir()` to test if there are multiple file with the same date:

```
Const DefaultPattern As String = "H:\data\test\testYYYYMMDD_??????.xlsx"
Dim FileName As String, Pattern As String
Pattern = Replace(DefaultPattern, "YYYYMMDD", Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD"))
FileName = Dir(Pattern)

If Len(FileName) > 0 Then
    If Len(Dir()) > 0 Then
        '2 or more files exists with the same Date
    End If
End If
```

You can get a collection of the file names like this:

```
Function getSamsFiles(DateOf As Date) As Collection
    Dim Pattern As String
    Pattern = "H:\data\test\test" & Format(DateOf, "YYYYMMDD") & "_??????.xlsx"
    Set getSamsFiles = getMatchingFiles()
End Function

Function getMatchingFiles(FileNamePattern As String)
    Dim FileName As String, Files As New Collection

    FileName = Dir(FileNamePattern)
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Files.Add FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    Set getMatchingFiles = Files

End Function
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the belated reply, I have been trying to learn VBA and all of its wicked challenges, thus far, not succeeding. I hace written code similar, but lets say I have `Format(Sheets(MacroSheet).Range("B3"), "YYYYMMDD")` I try to run the macro, and it just stops at this specific place saying "Constant Expression Required"

Comment: It seems like you are trying to assign a variable value to a const expression. 
 This video will explain it: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 26 - Constants and Enumerations (Const, Enum)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=d8cfrdUjcuw&index=29&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  I recommend that you watch the whole series.